# Nginx document root owner

Tags: nginx, documentroot

I am setting up a django web app using Nginx + Gunicorn. I am using also an Amazon linux instance that is based on CentOS distro. 
Assuming that Nginx is running with a nginx user what's the best practice for the document root folder?
Now I created /var/www/myapp folder that is owned by root. But I think that file uploads will not work for example because nginx cant create files in that folder.
Is it enough to give the owning to nginx user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real question is with what user is running Gunicorn .
To simplify everything you could make the whole /var/www/myapp folder (and files+childes) owned by the gunicorn user.
Or everything could be owned by a 3rd user, and only specific folders be owned by 'gunicorn'. These folder will be used for upload,cache, etc. The developer should know what folders needs to be writable .

Comment: Yes, indeed I need a user to run Gunicorn to avoid to run it with root privileges. I could use this user also to create a service startup script.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the "www-data" user in Debian but I think CentOS has an "apache" user. You could always use that user, or create "www-data" or "nginx".

(Note: in the examples below www-user could be any user you choose to setup).

1. In nginx conf set the user

   user       www-user www-user;  ## Default: nobody
2. Update owner for the www root to your www-user (and make sure the www-user has read/write permissions as required by your website).